# install_requires hierarchy: ContextualVersionConflict

Tags: python, pip, install-requires

Let's say I have a `main_package`.

In it's `setup.cfg` it has:

```
install_requires = 

     importlib_metadata; python_version < "3.8"

     not_main_package>= 15.1
```

Also I have a `not_main_package 16.0`.

In it's `setup.cfg` it has:

```
install_requires =

     importlib_metadata >= 3.6
```

I do:

`$ pip install importlib_metadata==1.5.0`
`$ install main_package`

I get an error:

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (importlib-metadata 1.5.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('importlib-metadata>=3.6'), {'not_main_package'})
```

Am I correct and the parent's (`main_package`) `install_requires` has higher priority and will ignore child's (`not_main_package`) `install_requires`, thus, causing the `ContextualVersionConflict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually install the needed version of `importlib_metadata`